# HTML Having text body start at a specific position in <li>

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am designing a page for a site and there are three different columns across. I was wondering how I could make the text (after the title) start exactly at a specific px spot? Like, something like 200px down front the start of the box.

That way I can have it line up with other boxes next to it.

This is how it currently displays, I want to learn how to make the sentence starting with **'The first interdisciplinary'** at a specific, defined, spot instead of just adding spaces.
[image: How it looks now]

Structure:

```
 <li class="one_third borderedbox lt_bg first"><img src="images/demo/onec.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="pad30">
      <h2 class="uppercase nospace push15"><i>2014</i><br>I Was Born For This </h2><br><br>

      <font size="2"><p class="nospace" align="left">The first Interdisciplinary Sacred Music....
```

Comment: You are currently using some invalid tags like `font` and attributes like `align`. When you need top space, you can either use `padding-top` or `margin-top` values.

Comment: please add a complete code so we have something to help you with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another easy way of achieving this is to control the height and padding of the heading instead of trying to control the paragraph text.

The `min-height` sets the minimum height the element should have so all elements under it would gather on the same line-height. Appropriate solution if you have a rough idea of the heights.

```
    h2 {
       min-height: 50px;
       padding-bottom: 10px;
       }
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the easiest solution :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can think of to accomplish your goal:

1. You could place each element of your column in its own div tag. Make the column that contains these smaller divs "position: relative;" and each of the smaller divs inside "position: absolute;"
       
      From there, you assign "top: 200px;" or whatever you wanted for each small div. This is starting at top of screen, working downward. Then set "left: 50px;" or whatever distance you want it from the left-hand side of the screen.
       
   I'm not saying this is the most elegant solution, but it will be an exact solution because you control down to the pixel where every element in your component ends up.
       
   See: [www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) for more on that solution.
2. You're alternative is to create specific height values to these smaller divs (ie "height: 50px;") and then use "margin-top: 10px;" (numbers are for you to decide) to place where those tags will start in reference to the div above it.
       
   See: 
       [www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin.asp) for more on this property.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using margins and padding? 
I would suggest that you open the current page in Google Chrome, and use developer tools (hit Ctrl+Shift+I) to look at the elements and code.

There, you can modify the CSS in real time and see what works. Tinker with the margins and padding there and I'm sure you will be able to do it.

After that, you can make the changes in your original css file.